# Lightning error :- Unknown controller action 'onSelectChange' Failing descriptor

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am unable to get selected value on change of picklist value in lightning Component. Below is my controller js and component.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.slds232 + '/assets/styles/salesforce-
      lightning-design-system.css'}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mySelectedText" type="String" default="some string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="contactLevel" type="String[]" default="Primary 
      Contact, Secondary Contact, Other" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onSelectChange}"/> 
      <div>
      <ui:inputSelect aura:id="levels" label="Contact Levels" change="
     {!c.onSelectChange}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.contactLevel}" var="level">
             <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!level}" label="{!level}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
   onSelectChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    var selected = component.find("levels").get("v.value");
    })
```

Comment: I think you are missing closing '}' of onSelectChange method in Javascript controller

Comment: If you are developing from Developer Console, You must get an error while saving your code. Winter 18 upgrade helping us in this syntax checks. For now, add the missing '}' in controller and check.

Comment: I missed here but I have already added in my code. So am still getting that error

Comment: what if you change the init handler to some other controller. I am assuming this could be a timing issue where the init method calls the onSelectChange before the inputselect renders on the page.

Comment: Hi You mean to say I should write this code in a helper and call the helper from controller?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out myself that i was adding my controller to other component.